# IIS7 Subdomain pages redirect to main domain

Tags: iis-7, dotnetnuke

I need to keep an old version of website in tact as a subdomain, so subdomain.domain.com points to the old IIS server running DNN and the default page appears fine.

However, any interior pages, /contact.aspx for example, return a 404 error. If I revert to ugly urls (default.aspx?TabId=##) the page works but attempts to redirect to domain.com instead of subdomain.domain.com.

Unfortunately I am unfamiliar with IIS and DNN, but the task is the task! Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will supply any additional details should anyone know what details I need to supply...

Note: a binding for the subdomain has been added, but the above happens with our without this addition.

Comment: What version of DNN are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added that "subdomain" as an Alias in DNN? You can do this in the PortalAlias table

Comment: That did it. Unfortunately this setting was not exposed in the admin, so I had to go into the database itself and add a row (should anyone else run into the same issue).

Comment: It is only exposed to the SuperUsers (host), so if you were only logged in as an Admin it wouldn't show.